# time.h:there is another '%' on the screen when print time

Tags: c, printf, time.h

This is a program I was trying to understand.

**SOURCE CODE**

```
typedef float Time;

Time getCurrentTime() {
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    Time currentTime;
    time ( &rawtime );                            //get system time
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );//convert to local time 
    // tm_hour, tm_min
    currentTime = (float)timeinfo->tm_hour + timeinfo->tm_min * 0.01;
    printf("InnerTime:%7.2f\n", currentTime);
    return currentTime;
}

int main(void) {
    Time tm = getCurrentTime();
    printf("OuterTime:%7.2f", tm);
    return 0;
}
```

---

### [image: Run Results]

Why there is another extra `%` in the end of `OuterTime`?
But there isn't `%` in the end of `InnerTime`!

Comment: I can see only one `%` in `OuterTime` also.

Comment: Do not post images of text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the outer time print, you missed to include a `newline` in the format string, so after the program prints the last output and exits, the prompt comes back right after the *printed* output.

Try

```
printf("OuterTime:%7.2f\n", tm);
```

to force the prompt to appear on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

That's very likely your shell prompt. Add a \n to be sure.